# Why are dynamically added widgets not displaying?

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-emulator, android-widget

My code RUNS (see source below), but the only widgets that are displaying are those from xml layout 
file. The dynamically created widgets, which code now runs without a hicc[ough,up], don't show 
themselves. Does anybody know why that would be? BTW, there are Contacts (4), and stepping through 
the code the values returned are valid.

The only thing in the vals that is strange is that two of the four Contact names has a "\t" between
the first and last name, a la "Barney\t Rubble" (I doubt this is a problem, but wonder why two would
have it, and two wouldn't, when I entered the Contact names in exactly the same manner...)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ondemandandautomatic_dynamicauthorize);

    ScrollView svh = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewHost);

    // Create a Linear Layout for each contact?
    LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);
    llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llp.weight = 1.0f;

    svh.addView(llay);

    // Contacts data snippet adapted from
    // http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/05/contacts-api-20-and-above-android.html
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            // The previous LinearLayout was added to the ScrollView; these
            // in the loop will be added to that one
            LinearLayout llayDynamic = new LinearLayout(this);
            llayDynamic.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llpDynamic = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            llpDynamic.weight = 1.0f;

            CheckBox cbOnDemand = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cbOnDemand.setTag(id);
            cbOnDemand.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llayDynamic.addView(cbOnDemand);

            CheckBox cbTime = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cbOnDemand.setTag(id);
            cbTime.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llayDynamic.addView(cbTime);

            CheckBox cbSpace = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cbOnDemand.setTag(id);
            cbSpace.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llayDynamic.addView(cbSpace);

            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setTag(id);
            tv.setText(name);
            tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llayDynamic.addView(tv);

            llayDynamic.invalidate();

        }
        // One cat on stackOverflow said to do this, another said it
        // would be unnecessary
        svh.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Update:
OK, I fixed the problem with the widgets not displaying by adding:

```
            llay.addView(llayDynamic);
```

...before the possibly unnecessary call to llayDynamic.invalidate()

HOWEVER, the widgets as displayed are still a mess. See http://warbler.posterous.com/widgets-are-still-deformedimitating-brain-dea to see what I mean.

I reckon I can get things to space better by experimenting with padding properties and such, but the first child LinearLayout appearing to the right (on the same row) with the parent LinearLayout (child of the ScrollView) is a problem.

Why would it do this, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You never add anything to the `LinearLayout` called `llay`, which is inside your `ScrollView`.

Try adding this inside your `while` loop:

```
llay.addView(llayDynamic);
```

Comment: yup, just having a LinearLayout Object somewhere in memory does not draw it.

Comment: check if `scrollViewHost` is setup correctly. E.g. add some TextViews in the Layout Editor

Comment: Check your layout, what is your `ScrollView` inside of? If it's inside another `LinearLayout`, make sure its orientation is `vertical`, it looks like you've got it inside a `horizontal` layout.

Comment: When I change the LinearLayout that is the parent of the ScrollView to vertical, the dynamically created widgets look pretty good, but the widgets declared in the xml layout stack on top of each other (vertically) as one would expect, which doesn't work for me. I need all of the rows to flow left-to-right.

Comment: What happens is that the first dynamically created row (the second row, that is) appears to the right of the first, whereas I want it on a new row. And then each subsequent row is left-aligned with that scrunched row, so ALL of the dynamically-created widgets are scrunched together...maybe I need to use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout?

Comment: RelativeLayout is tricky, I tend to favor LinearLayout for simple things like this. Consider posting your entire layout XML, in a new question maybe.